# How to convert string to Date by TypeScript

Tags: angular, string, typescript, date

Can I convert to `20200408` these string to Date by TypeScript? If it is yes, then how can?

Comment: Please do some research and show the results of that research, and any attempts you made to solve the problem yourself, in the question. That string could be any one of a large number of dates, depending on the format. May 8, 2020? Sep 4, 2020? Sep 20, 2004?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all such strings have the exact same format, you can split them as such (and assuming your format is YYYYMMDD):

```
let dateStr = '20200408';

let year = dateStr.slice(0,4);
let month = dateStr.slice(4, 6);
let day = dateStr.slice(6, 8);

let date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates, especially with guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "20200408" refers to 2020-04-08 in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
let full_date_string = "20200408";

let year = Number(full_date_string.substring(0,4));
let month = Number(full_date_string.substring(4,6));
let day = Number(full_date_string.substring(6,8));

let date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code worked for me.

```
let dateS = '2020-05-27T00:00:00' 
let dateObj = new Date(dateS);
```

You can also check below link for conversion in angular.

https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Comment: How is that the same string as what the OP has in the question?

Comment: This does not answer the question - see OP's string format.

Comment: My bad... I missed the string format mention in question. I have just seen for String to date conversion statement. Thanks for pointing this out.